# getting latitude and longitude information from a web visitor

Tags: google-maps, ip-address

TO use google maps it seems you have to have the lat and long for a visitor to plot them on a map.

Are there any free libraries that will give you this information given a IP address?

Comment: exact dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348614/how-to-determine-a-zip-code-and-city-from-an-ip-address

Answer (score 2):

Here's one: http://www.ip2location.com/developers.aspx

Of course, you're only going to get a *rough* idea of where the user *probably* is.  If you're expecting the kind of accuracy that you see on crime shows you'll be sadly disappointed. :)

Comment: I didn't ask for a VB GUI application to track down the killer now did I? hehe

Answer (score 1):

Check out [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/help/) and [hostip.info](http://www.hostip.info/use.html)